# Why can't Jane give blood?

Tags: cancer, blood-donation

I have a friend, lets call her Jane. Jane is not allowed to give blood, this is because she has a medical condition whereby she is prone to having polyps in her digestive system. As I understand this means she has a higher risk of cancer.

Can this sort of cancer be passed through blood and if not why is this restriction in place? I.e what is this a precaution against? The situation may be more complicated than I realise, but this is my basic understanding.

If it's relevant Jane lives in the UK.

Comment: What is her exact medical diagnosis? For example, familial adenomatous polyposis is a hereditary condition in which numerous polyps in the colon become cancerous at young age.

Comment: I don't know for sure, I know it's hereditary but it's not really appropriate to probe Jane in this case to fulfill my own curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume she is at risk for developing bowel malignancy at some time in the future.  So, unless she is screened very regularly, then if she is accepted as a blood donor, she might be donating blood while she is in a cancerous state.  Now, is there evidence of the ability to transfer cancer from one person to another via blood transfusion?  This has been looked at historically and

> Despite the many millions of units transfused
>   since the advent of allogeneic blood transfusion,
>   there is no evidence to support the theoretical
>   concern that cancer could be transmitted via blood.
>   Apart from the United States and Australia, though,
>   most blood services still practice a precautionary
>   exclusion of donors with a history of cancer based
>   on experience in organ transplantation and, to a
>   lesser extent, HSCT

[Can Blood Tranfusion Transmit Cancer? A Literature Review](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tmrv.2010.03.005)

So, the UK blood transfusion service is adopting the same precautionary approach.

But there is evidence that as yet unknown carcinogenic agents are transmitted by blood transfusion.

> In a large cohort of UK women, transfusions in the 21st century were associated with long-term increased risks of liver cancer and non-Hodgkin lymphoma. Some of these malignancies may have been caused by carcinogenic agents that are not currently screened for in transfused blood.

[Cancer risk among 21st century blood transfusion recipients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5391695/)

> A large study from Denmark and Sweden reported relative risks 5–9 years after blood transfusion in 1992–2002 of 1.86 for liver cancer and 1.20 for non-Hodgkin lymphoma

[Cancer incidence in blood transfusion recipients.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18073377/)

The likely candidates are Epstein-Barr virus and hepatitis G both of which are not screened for in blood donors.